# Can I run multiple Selenium instances in multiple already opened Browsers?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, batch-file, selenium-webdriver

I have a Program that opens batch files in a For-Loop. The Name of the Programs is something like:

```
chrome1.bat
chrome2.bat
chrome3.bat
...
```

So the For-Loop looks like that:

```
def open_browsers():
    browser_count = 1
    for x in range(how_many_user):
        subprocess.Popen('chrome'+str(browser_count)+'.bat')
        browser_count += 1
        time.sleep(55)
```

(how_many_user = 10)
In the Batch-Files is the following:

```
In chrome1.bat is: chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9250
In chrome2.bat is: chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9251
In chrome3.bat is: chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9252
and so on...
```

I am trying to work with these Browser through Selenium, the following is my Code:

```
def make_everything_else():
    product_page = 'https://www.nike.com'
    this_port = 0 
    for x in range(how_many_user):    
        port = port_file[this_port]
        str(port)
        time.sleep(60)
        options = Options()
        options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:'+port)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        browser.get(product_page)
        this_port += 1
```

The 'port_file' is defined as the following:

```
d = open('chrome_profiles.txt', 'r')
port_file = d.read().splitlines()
```

In the 'chrome_profiles.txt' are basically just all the Ports written down, that I use to start Chrome.

```
9250
9251
9252
9253
9254
9255
9256
9257
9258
9259
```

My Problem is, that it is starting all of the Browsers under their specific Port, but Selenium does only Work in the first Browser, and does nothing in the others that get started.

Oh and I am using Threads to start them both at the same time:

```
start_browser = threading.Thread(target=open_browsers)
start_browser.start()

do_the_other_stuff = threading.Thread(target=make_everything_else)
do_the_other_stuff.start()
```

Comment: Can I run multiple Selenium instances in multiple already opened Browsers? - you can have multiple selenium instances but I don't think so that could happen over already opened window

Comment: Same, because you will need something to control those browsers ( driver ). On already opened browsers, you don't have any control. 
what I can suggest is, see if you can open new window from first launched instance and perform the tasks.
If what you said is actually possible then forgive me for my shallow knowledge and desperately waiting for enlightenment.

Comment: Yes, actually you can control already opened Browsers trough that way, but somehow you can't control multiple opened Browsers in one Program. But you're right, to control the already opened Browser you need a webdriver, in my Case I use the Chrome Driver.